# Calculate percentage of outliers in each column of a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, types, outliers

I have a dataframe called `myvolabserr` and I want to calculate the percentage of the values>10% of each column.
I do that in a way that

1. check if the value is an outlier to a new dataframe which consists of T/F (T if value>10%)
2. calculate the percentage of T values in each column

I am doing the 1st step, I tried

```
out = myvolabserr
for i in range(0, len(out.axes[1])):
    out.iloc[:,i] = myvolabserr.iloc[:,i].apply(lambda x: 'True' if x > 0.1 else 'False')
print(out)
```

but I got error saying that

```
'>' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'float'
```

And then I check the types of my df `myvolabserr`:

```
                             ticker
Absolute Error (Volatility)  AAPL      float64
                             AMD        object
                             BIDU      float64
                             GOOGL     float64
                             IXIC      float64
                             MSFT      float64
                             NDXT      float64
                             NVDA      float64
                             NXPI      float64
                             QCOM      float64
                             SWKS      float64
                             TXN       float64
dtype: object
```

Can anyone help with the error?
And maybe is there any other way to calculate the percentage of the outliers in one go instead of my 2-step way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Loops here are not necessary, convert values to numeric and compare by scalar:

```
out = myvolabserr.astype(float) > 0.1
```

For percentages use `mean` - `True`s are processing like `1`s:

```
s = out.mean()
```

Comment: Thank you. It works, and may I ask the possible reason that the type of AMD is different? Because I process the data files in the same way.

Comment: @Lazer - Hard question, not idea.